# Behaviour of spring boot LocaleChangeInterceptor in a multithreaded environment

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-boot, localization, locale

I am using following class to manage localization in my spring boot application.

```
@Configuration
public class MessageConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageConfig.class);
    /**
     * Message source for localization.
     * @return message source.
     */
    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Creating a ResourceBundleMessageSource.");
        }
        ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        source.setBasename("messages");
        source.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        return source;
    }

    /**
     * Utility for localization.
     * @return locale resolver.
     */
    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Creating a locale resolver.");
        }
        SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
        return slr;
    }

    /**
     * Utility for localization.
     * @return locale change interpreter.
     */
    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Creating a locale change interceptor.");
        }
        LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        lci.setParamName("lang");
        return lci;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Adding locale change interceptor to registry.");
        }
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }

}
```

My application decides the locale to be used based on the lang URL parameter sent to the API.

When I send `localhost:8080/api`, it sends content in default language, which is english.
If I send `localhost:8080/api?lang=si`, it sends content in Sinhala language.

However, if I send a request to `localhost:8080/api` without specifying the lang, I receive content in Sinhala language, which was used in the previous call, instead of the default locale.
I am using `LocaleContextHolder` in service layer to decide the content of the output.
 My understanding is each seperate call to API will be handled by a new thread. So, why the default locale has been changed to 'si', in this API call even when I have not specified the lang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`LocaleChangeInterceptor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/LocaleChangeInterceptor.html) changes the language based on the fact if the request parameter is present or not. If this parameter is present it will get the `Locale` and use the [`LocaleResolver.setLocale`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/LocaleResolver.html#setLocale-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-java.util.Locale-) method to change the language for the current user.

All the code that needs the `Locale` for translating messages use the [`LocaleResolver.resolveLocale`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/LocaleResolver.html#resolveLocale-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-) method to obtain it.

Now as you are using the [`SessionLocaleResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/SessionLocaleResolver.html) it will be stored in the users `HttpSession`. So after it being changed it will remain the same for the current http session **NOT** for other session. If you remove the session cookie in your browser it will be the default language again.

You can test this by opening a new differnt browser (not the same browser as this will copy the session state) or an incognito window of your browser and check your site. It will still be in the default language and not the changed language.

Comment: I am using SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS and calling the API through a java client. I don't send a session header in my request.

Comment: I tried with an incognito window and it used the default locale when I did not specify the locale. Should I use a different implementation of the LocaleResolver in my use case instead of SessionLocaleResolver?

Comment: The fact that you are using `SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS` is only for Spring Security NOT for the remainder of your application. So this doesn't prevent your other parts of the application to use the `HttpSession`!. Why should you use a different implementation? What do you want to achieve (your question wasn't about that so you might want to ask another one!).

Comment: I don't need a different implementation in that case. I thought maybe it is not correct to use  SessionLocaleResolver with SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS. But your comment clears that doubt. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`SessionLocaleResolver` retrieves the locale from user's session. My guess is that once the locale is set, it uses the previously set value. From the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/SessionLocaleResolver.html):

> LocaleResolver implementation that uses a locale attribute in the
>   user's session in case of a custom setting, with a fallback to the
>   specified default locale or the request's accept-header locale.

As to why it doesn't change, it's probably because `LocaleChangeInterceptor` isn't triggered when you request `/api` without the `lang` parameter.